sample using negated normal via numpy
I have a sorted list that I need to sample from. I want to favor the items towards each end of the list. In other words, I want to sample from the list using a negated normal function such that the first and last entries of the list are chosen more frequently than items in the middle of the list. I tried this:
slots = np.floor(np.random.normal(scale=len(children)//2, size=max_children)) - max_children//2
return children[slots]

However, it returns numbers that are out of range. It also returns duplicate numbers. What can I do better?

It looks like you're sampling from the normal distribution itself, but you said you wanted to invert it - like, sample from a distribution shaped like the reciprocal of the normal PDF? In any case, the normal distribution has infinite support, so you'd have to truncate the values it produces (e.g. with np.clip).  You could also use a beta distribution with parameters less than one. The support is finite, and you wouldn't need to invert anything. You will get duplicates unless you do something to prevent it. Random is random.

You do not want a negated normal nor an inverted normal. You rather want a beta distribution with the shape parameters equal to each other and strictly less than 1. Check the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution when alpha = beta = 0.5. Thats what you want

You could always rotate the list by half its length - then the previous ends will be in the middle and you could simply use a clipped standard normal distribution.

As your are working with a list of discrete values I would argue you would rather work with a multinomial distribution of the list indices. In Numpy this can be done conveniently with the np.random.choice method, which directly takes the probabilities associated with each entry. Here is a minimal example:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random_state = np.random.RandomState(4873)

children = np.arange(20)

p = norm.pdf(np.arange(len(children)), loc=(len(children) - 1) / 2, scale=10)
p = p.max() - p + 0.01 # to prevent samples in the middle end up with zero probability
samples = random_state.choice(children, p=p / p.sum(), size=10_000)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))

axes[0].bar(children, p)
axes[0].set_title("Probability mass function")

axes[1].hist(samples, bins=np.arange(len(children) + 1) - 0.5, density=True, alpha=0.5)
axes[1].set_title("Samples")

Which plots:

I also think random.choice also makes the intention of drawing sampled from the list much more clear.
However the point of possibly using a beta distribution is still valid. In this case you would still convert it to a probability mass function as shown above.
I hope this helps!
